# histogram chops off after 10 on the horizontal axis

Tags: python

My program creates a histogram from a dictionary. It first reads in text from a text file. Then it counts and prints out the length of each word. For example, the words "in", "the", and "Florida" would produce a count like this. 
Length Count
2      1
3      1
7      1
Because there are only 1 word of length 2, 1 word of length 3 and 1 word of length 7. My text file has hundreds of words. So, there are some words that are of length 10 and greater. But after 10 on the horizontal axis it doesn't show anything. Please help. Below is my code.

```
import sys
import string


def rem_punc(w):

    plst = list(string.punctuation)
    for p in plst:
        if p in w:
            w = w.replace(p,'')
    return w


def word_length_processor(text):

    d = dict()
    for w in text:
       w = rem_punc(w)
       if len(w) > 0:
           n = len(w)
           if n not in d:
               d[n] = 1
           else:
                   d[n] = d[n] + 1

    for k,v in d.items():
        print("{0}      {1}".format(k,v))

    print()
    hist_maker(d)

def hist_maker(d):
    freq = d
    for y in range(300,9,-10): 
        print ("{:>6} | ".format(y), end="") 
        for x in range(1,10):   
            if freq.get(x,0) >= y:  
                column = "***"
            else:
                column = "   "
            print(column, end="") 
        print() 
    print("       ------------------------------------------------------")
    print("          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15")



arg_string = sys.argv[1]

try:
        f = open(arg_string, 'r')
except:
        print('Could not open file. Please try again.')
        sys.exit()



text = f.read()
f.close()
text = text.split()

print("{0} {1}".format("Length","Count"))

print(word_length_processor(text))
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of `for x in range(1,10):` in `hist_maker` function?

Comment: It print the horizontal sections. But even if I use 20 or 100 instead of 10 it still chops off the bars.